# Site and Custom URL Limit

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com, custom-domain, mydomain

I am getting error when trying to add new custom URL for site:-

## ERROR:-

"Site Customer can't be added because domains are limited to 50 sites".

I can see Maximum no. of sites which can be created are 25, hence I checked the below doc

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_overview.htm&language=en_US

Question 1:-   It says that each domain can have up to 50 sites,? Can anyone please explain it in more detail? If it is about limit of site then as per edition it should be 25 and it is actually 25.

Question 1 (a) What is the total number of custom URL we can create for a site? and can it be increased?

Question 2:- Moreover it says that we can ""set up a single domain to host your Communities, Force.com, and Site.com sites""

But we know that force.com domain and community Domain cannot be same.

Question 3:- It is difficult for me to understand for which domain we are talking about in above doc, custom domain or standard domain??

Your answer are really appreciated!!!